# Passing bash variable to perl one-liners - insights required

Tags: perl, bash

I am fairly new to Perl and I have been toying with one-liners to get some file operations done. I am using Perl to print segment between defined by line numbers which are obtained from another file. My current issue is as follows:

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print $_ if $. == $ENV{var}' filename.txt
```

prints line number 10, but if i want to print from line 10 to the end of file, i tried

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print if $ENV{var} .. -1' filename.txt
```

--fails. The output generated prints the whole file. Additionally, the following works,

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print if $. >= $ENV{var} $$ $. <= $ENV{var}+5 ' filename.txt
```

But since i am dealing with a variable file length after the required line, this is not a viable solution.

Comment: Why not simply `tail +"$var" file` or `sed -n "$var,\$p" file`?

Answer (score 3):

Perl flip-flop operator has some of his own warts (like *is my variable line number or boolean?*), so when in doubt do explicit comparison to `$.` line number.

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print if $.== $ENV{var} .. -1' filename.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Environmental variables:

```
var=10; echo "$(seq 20 35)" | perl -lne 'print if $. >= '"$var"';'
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
```

Take a look at the way I escaped `$var`

Using flip-flop:

```
var=10; echo "$(seq 20 35)" | perl -lne 'print if $.== '"$var"' .. -1;'
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
```

Answer (score 1):

From line 10 to the end of the file:

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print $_ if $. > $ENV{var}' filename.txt
```

If you want it to include line 10:

```
export var=10 ; perl -ne 'print $_ if $. >= $ENV{var}' filename.txt
```